# jQuery fadeIn not actually fading in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function where certain divs fade in and out, I cant paste my entire file into a jsFiddle as its too large and all image links are relative, I have the following however...

```
// On click hide default, Country specific
    $('.default .asia').click(function(){
        $('.default').fadeOut("fast");
        $(".default").queue(function () {
            $('.viewport-asia').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.viewport-asia').dequeue();
        });         
    });
    $('.default .north-america').click(function(){
        $('.default').fadeOut("fast");
        $(".default").queue(function () {
            $('.viewport-america').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.viewport-america').dequeue();
        });
    });
    $('.default .europe').click(function(){
        $('.default').fadeOut("fast");
        $(".default").queue(function () {
            $('.viewport-europe').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.viewport-europe').dequeue();
        });
    });

    // Drag event
    $(".america-big").draggable();
    $(".europe-big").draggable();
    $(".asia-big").draggable();

    // Reset map
    $('a.zoom-out').click(function(){
        $('.hidden').fadeOut("fast");
        $(".hidden").queue(function () {
            $('.default').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.hidden').dequeue();
        }); 
    })
});
```

The last function // Reset Map "a.zoom-out" should fade out the current div and fade in the .default div, its currently fading out the current div but the default div isn't fading back in?

Can anybody see where im going wrong?

---

HTML

```
<div class="map">

    <!-- // Default Map -->
    <div class="default">
        <div class="asia"><img src="map/asia.png" alt="Asia"></div>
        <div class="north-america"><img src="map/north-america.jpg" alt="America"></div>
        <div class="europe"><img src="map/europe.jpg" alt="Europe"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- // Animated Map // North America -->
    <div class="viewport-america hidden">
        <div class="compass">
            <a href="#" class="arrow top">Top</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow right">Right</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow bottom">Bottom</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow left">Left</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</a>
        <div class="instructions"><img src="map/instructions.png" alt="Instructions"></div>
        <div class="america-big"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1989/996" alt="America" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- // Animated Map // Europe -->
    <div class="viewport-europe hidden">
        <div class="compass">
            <a href="#" class="arrow top">Top</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow right">Right</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow bottom">Bottom</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow left">Left</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</a>
        <div class="instructions"><img src="map/instructions.png" alt="Instructions"></div>
        <div class="europe-big"><img src="http://placekitten.com/2000/1000" alt="Europe" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- // Animated Map // Asia -->
    <div class="viewport-asia hidden">
        <div class="compass">
            <a href="#" class="arrow top">Top</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow right">Right</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow bottom">Bottom</a>
            <a href="#" class="arrow left">Left</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</a>
        <div class="instructions"><img src="map/instructions.png" alt="Instructions"></div>
        <div class="asia-big"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1999/999" alt="Asia" /></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're mixing double quotes and single quotes; never a good idea. Also, I suggest you take a look at [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs, Im quite new to jQuery so not to sure of the best practices for something like this, I'll take a look at what you mentioned...

Comment: I've added the HTML @SivaCharan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `queue` function.

If you want the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` at the same time:

```
$('.default .asia').click(function(){
    $('.default').fadeOut("fast");
    $('.viewport-asia').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

If you want the `fadeOut` first and after it finishes the `fadeIn`:

```
$('.default .asia').click(function(){
    $('.default').fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $('.viewport-asia').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```